# Trying to integrate Agora IO with Unity WebGL. Error when building demo scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, videochat, agora.io

**Problem description**

When building the demo scene in Unity for webgl, and then loading it, the scene loads, but when I click join, I get an error saying 'abort(To use dlopen, you need to use Emscripten's linking support...). [Screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7dJH.jpg)

**Background information**

I've done some googling. Here is someone having the same problem: https://dev.to/joelthomas362/create-an-agora-group-video-chat-using-unity-33ce (scroll down to the comments).

I think it has something to do with the way the agora DLL's are linked (see this thread for example: https://forum.unity.com/threads/to-use-dlopen-you-need-to-use-emscriptens-linking-support.521968/) where a unity Dev posts: *Dynamic linking, i.e. @DllImport statements, are not supported by WebAssembly (in a form that would be useful to Unity WebGL plugin builds at least). When compiling plugins, the plugins should be authored to link statically to the project instead.* However, I can't find how to statically link Agora IO.

**Question**

Is it possible to get Agora IO to work with Unity WebGL, and if so, how?

**How to reproduce**

- Download Agora video SDK for unity (2.9.2)
- Import SDK into unity
- Enter AppID in GameController object from the demo.
- Go to 'build settings'. Add SceneHome and ScenHelloVideo from the demo to 'Scenes in build'. Click 'WebGl'. Click 'Switch platform', then build (might take a while).
- Upload the output files to a server (WebGl builds in Unity don't open locally in Chrome).
- Open the index.html file on the server.
- The scene loads. Click 'join'. Now you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Agora Video SDK for Unity does NOT support WebGL.  It is on the future development roadmap however.  Please stay tuned for the updates.

Comment: Can you provide any indicated timeline for WebGL support please

Comment: very surprised webgl is not supported

Comment: Please understand Web/browser and native use totally different underlying technology stacks.  And demand drives product roadmap.  At Agora we listen to your needs, and the WebGL plugin is under development right now.  You should see it before Fall this year.